# columns in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have dataset like this

```
+--------------+---------+
|flavor        |type     |
+--------------+---------+
|chocolate     |ice cream|
|strawberry    |  cake   |
|chocolate     |  cake   |
|chocolate     |ice cream|
|strawberry    |ice cream|
+--------------+---------+
```

I need to create another column("total") with the total number of

> - flavors regardless of the type and
> - flavor and type combined

All of this in the same table which will have 3 columns like below:

```
+--------------+---------+--------+
|flavor        |type     |total   |
+--------------+---------+--------+
|chocolate     |ice cream|   2    |
|chocolate     |  cake   |   1    | 
|chocolate     |  null   |   3    |
|strawberry    |  cake   |   1    |
|strawberry    |ice cream|   1    |
|strawberry    | null    |   2    |
+--------------+---------+--------+
```

I tried this code `df.groupBy("flavor,"type").agg(F.count(df['flavor']).alias("total"))`

Comment: Would be great if you can add your final dataset with `total` column

Comment: I just added the total column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rollup`

```
df.rollup('flavor','type').count() \
    .where('flavor is not null or type is not null') \
    .selectExpr('flavor', 'type', 'count as total') \
    .show()
# Where cluase is to remove total count=5 (flavor and type both null)

+----------+--------+-----+
|    flavor|    type|total|
+----------+--------+-----+
| chocolate|    cake|    1|
| chocolate|    null|    3|
|strawberry|    cake|    1|
| chocolate|icecream|    2|
|strawberry|    null|    2|
|strawberry|icecream|    1|
+----------+--------+-----+
```